# How to separate string's with pipe

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I have a line with the following description: '|0200|4|SALGADOS|||KG|00|19051000||||17|'

I want to separate where the pipe to save data in the database.

I'm using the pos function incorrectly. But I am getting the data.

Inside the if then i will insert data into db.

```
ReadLn(txt, line);
if True then
  if (Pos('|0200|', line)) = 1 then
  begin
    fArq.Add(line);
  end;
  if (pos('|0000|', line)) = 1 then
  begin
    fArq.Add(line);
  end;
  if (pos('|0005|', line)) = 1 then
  begin
    fArq.Add(line);
  end;
  if (pos('|C460|', line)) = 1 then
  begin
    fArq.Add(line);
    flagCF := True;
  end
  else
  begin
    if flagCF = True then
      if (pos('|C490|', line)) = 0 then
        fArq.Add(line)
      else
        flagCF := False;
  end
```

Comment: I don't understand. What pipes are you referring to ? Btw., you can add `else` for each of your `if` blocks because once you find a match, then there is no other one matching.

Comment: @TLama:  I think the OP means the "vertical bar" symbol, often called a "pipe" symbol here, ymmv.

Comment: @MartynA, oh, thanks. I was immediately thinking of some database pipe.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use TStringList:

```
lStringList := TStringList.Create;
lStringList.delimiter := '|';
lStringList.DelimitedText := '|0200|4|SALGADOS|||KG|00|19051000||||17|';
```

Now you can access each field using lStringList.Items[ index ]

---

**Note** (from comments): if space characters is included in the string, set `StrictDelimiter` to true to avoid treating them as delimiters.

Comment: [`SplitString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.StrUtils.SplitString) will work (won't ignore empty chars) here too. Or just `Line.Split(['|'])` using the string helper.

Comment: If you use `DelimitedText`, don't forget to set `StrictDelimiter` to true.

Comment: Yes, if spaces can appear in the delimited text, then StrictDelimiter should be set to true.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance but I can not find a way to extract the items. lStringList.Items[ index ]. This function does not exist for me. I am trying to manipulate the cont.

Comment: index is a number. lStringList.Items[0] is the first element, lStringList.Items[1] is the second element, up to the last element lStringList.Items[lStringList.Count-1].

Comment: After some tests, using the delimiter |, it also defines whitespace blank. How to remove it? Example: line '|0200|3|CARNE BOVINA ALMONDEGA|||KG|00|02013000||||12|'. 02013000 = item [10]
right is [8]

Comment: @Hans, I added this information to the answer. One should not have to read comments to get valuable information. That is the consensus here at SO at least :-)

Answer (score 2):

With [`ExtractStrings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Classes.ExtractStrings), you can add all values between the |'s to a `TStrings`-descendant.

Assuming `fArq` is a `TStrings` descendent:

```
ExtractStrings(['|'], [], PChar(line), fArq);
```

Comment: Note that ExtractStrings will not store empty strings. So if you must know that the "KG" in the example above is in the 7th position, this may not work for you.

Comment: @PabloRicardo:  Better to avoid "for".  Either of the answers you've received is better than trying to parse the data yourself - quicker to get right, less error prone and easier to maintain/apply to other data.

Comment: @DaleM +1 That's correct. But that specific functioning could just be desirable too.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Delphi XE3 and up you can use the [Split](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/de/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.Split) Class Helper Method.

```
 parts:=line.Split(['|'],TStringSplitOptions.ExcludeEmpty);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the following functions that I've been using for quite some time.

There are two variants here, the first one is a one time use type of function and the other is when you want to efficiently process the entire input string from the first element up to the last in order.

I have also included the related functions to count the number of sections.

P.S. These functions are actually 1 based, as written.
P.P.S. I ripped the functions from another unit and haven't checked this unit for complete correctness.  YMMV.

The non POS methods are considered one-off functions.  ie. You are only looking for a single value in the given input string.

The POS methods take two addition integer variables to store internal index positions for later use.  The initial value of the variables should be set to -1 for the first call.  After that you should just provide the values to the next iteration of the call that the previous call returned.

For example.

Non-POS use:

```
const
  Str1 = '|0200|4|SALGADOS|||KG|00|19051000||||17|';

.
.
.

begin
  showmessage( ParseSection(Str1, 1, '|') );  //returns 0200
  showmessage( ParseSection(Str1, 4, '|') );  //returns '' (empty string)


  //this will show every element in the string once
  Idx1 := -1;
  Idx2 := -1;
  for loop := 1 to CountSections(Str1, '|') do
    showmessage( ParseSectionPos(Str1, loop, '|', Idx1, Idx2) );  
  //Idx1 and Idx2 are self referenced variables and don't need outside intervention
  //These are necessary to obtain the best possible speed
end;
```

The other variations of the methods allow for quoted values and the quoting character to be user defined.

```
unit rmControls.Strings.Sections;

interface

uses System.Classes, System.SysUtils;

function CountSections(const ParseLine: string; const ParseSep: char): integer; overload;
function CountSections(const ParseLine: string; const ParseSep: char; const QuotedStrChar: char): integer; overload;

function ParseSection(const ParseLine: string; ParseNum: integer; const ParseSep: char): string; overload;
function ParseSection(const ParseLine: string; ParseNum: integer; const ParseSep: char; const QuotedStrChar: char): string; overload;

function ParseSectionPos(const ParseLine: string; ParseNum: integer; const ParseSep: char; var FromIDX, FromPOS: integer): string; overload;
function ParseSectionPos(const ParseLine: string; ParseNum: integer; const ParseSep: char; const QuotedStrChar: char; var FromIDX, FromPOS: integer): string; overload;

function UpdateSection(const ParseLine, UpdateText: string; ParseNum: integer; const ParseSep: char):string; overload;
function UpdateSection(const ParseLine, UpdateText: string; ParseNum: integer; const ParseSep: char; const QuotedStrChar: char):string; overload;

function UpdateSectionPos(const ParseLine, UpdateText: string; ParseNum: integer; const ParseSep: char; var FromIDX, FromPOS: integer):string; overload;
function UpdateSectionPos(const ParseLine, UpdateText: string; ParseNum: integer; const ParseSep: char; const QuotedStrChar: char; var FromIDX, FromPOS: integer):string; overload;

implementation

uses System.Math, System.Masks, System.Character, System.Variants;

function CountSections(const ParseLine: string; const ParseSep: char; const QuotedStrChar: char): integer; overload;
var
  wEnd: PChar;
  Loop: integer;
  wInQuote: boolean;
begin
  wInQuote := false;
  wEnd := PChar(ParseLine);
  result := 0;

  for Loop := 1 to Length(ParseLine) do
  begin
    if (wEnd^ = QuotedStrChar) then
      wInQuote := not wInQuote;

    if not wInQuote and (wEnd^ = ParseSep) then
      inc(result);
    inc(wEnd);
  end;
  if Length(ParseLine) <> 0 then
    inc(result);
end; { CountSections }

function CountSections(const ParseLine: string; const ParseSep: char): integer; overload;
var
  wEnd: PChar;
  Loop: integer;
begin
  wEnd := PChar(ParseLine);
  result := 0;
  for Loop := 1 to Length(ParseLine) do
  begin
    if (wEnd^ = ParseSep) then
      inc(result);
    inc(wEnd);
  end;
  if Length(ParseLine) <> 0 then
    inc(result);
end; { CountSections }

function ParseSection(const ParseLine: string; ParseNum: integer; const ParseSep: char): string; overload;
var
  w1, w2: integer;
begin
  w1 := -1;
  w2 := -1;
  result := ParseSectionPos(ParseLine, ParseNum, ParseSep, w1, w2);
end; { ParseSection }

function ParseSection(const ParseLine: string; ParseNum: integer; const ParseSep: char; const QuotedStrChar: char): string;  overload;
var
  w1, w2: integer;
begin
  w1 := -1;
  w2 := -1;
  result := ParseSectionPos(ParseLine, ParseNum, ParseSep, QuotedStrChar, w1, w2);
end; { ParseSection }

function ParseSectionPos(const ParseLine: string; ParseNum: integer; const ParseSep: char; var FromIDX, FromPOS: integer): string;
var
  wStart, wEnd: PChar;
  wIndex, Loop: integer;
  wLoopIDX: integer;
begin
  wIndex := 1;
  wLoopIDX := 1;
  wEnd := PChar(ParseLine);
  if (FromIDX > -1) and (FromIDX < Length(ParseLine)) then
  begin
    inc(wEnd, FromIDX);
    wIndex := FromPOS;
    wLoopIDX := FromIDX;
  end;
  wStart := wEnd;

  for Loop := wLoopIDX to Length(ParseLine) do
  begin
    if (wEnd^ = ParseSep) then
    begin
      if wIndex = ParseNum then
        break
      else
      begin
        inc(wIndex);
        inc(wEnd);
        wStart := wEnd;
      end;
    end
    else
      inc(wEnd);
  end;

  if wIndex = ParseNum then
  begin
    SetString(result, wStart, wEnd - wStart);
    if result = #0 then
      result := '';
    FromIDX := wEnd - PChar(ParseLine);
    FromPOS := ParseNum;
  end
  else
    result := '';
end;

function ParseSectionPos(const ParseLine: string; ParseNum: integer; const ParseSep: char; const QuotedStrChar: char; var FromIDX, FromPOS: integer): string;
var
  wStart, wEnd: PChar;
  wIndex, Loop: integer;
  wInQuote: boolean;
  wLoopIDX: integer;
begin
  wInQuote := false;
  wIndex := 1;
  wLoopIDX := 1;

  wEnd := PChar(ParseLine);
  if (FromIDX > -1) and (FromIDX < Length(ParseLine)) then
  begin
    inc(wEnd, FromIDX);
    wIndex := FromPOS;
    wLoopIDX := FromIDX;
  end;
  wStart := wEnd;

  for Loop := wLoopIDX to Length(ParseLine) do
  begin
    if (wEnd^ = QuotedStrChar) then
      wInQuote := not wInQuote;

    if not wInQuote and (wEnd^ = ParseSep) then
    begin
      if wIndex = ParseNum then
        break
      else
      begin
        inc(wIndex);
        inc(wEnd);
        wStart := wEnd;
      end;
    end
    else
      inc(wEnd);
  end;

  if wIndex = ParseNum then
  begin
    SetString(result, wStart, wEnd - wStart);
    if (Length(result) > 0) and (result[1] = QuotedStrChar) then
      result := AnsiDequotedStr(result, QuotedStrChar);
    if result = #0 then
      result := '';
    FromIDX := wEnd - PChar(ParseLine);
    FromPOS := ParseNum;
  end
  else
    result := '';
end;

function UpdateSection(const ParseLine, UpdateText: string; ParseNum: integer; const ParseSep: char): string; overload;
var
  w1, w2: integer;
begin
  w1 := -1;
  w2 := -1;
  result := UpdateSectionPos(ParseLine, UpdateText, ParseNum, ParseSep, w1, w2);
end;

function UpdateSection(const ParseLine, UpdateText: string; ParseNum: integer; const ParseSep: char; const QuotedStrChar: char): string; overload;
var
  w1, w2: integer;
begin
  w1 := -1;
  w2 := -1;
  result := UpdateSectionPos(ParseLine, UpdateText, ParseNum, ParseSep, QuotedStrChar, w1, w2);
end;

function UpdateSectionPos(const ParseLine, UpdateText: string; ParseNum: integer; const ParseSep: char; var FromIDX, FromPOS: integer):string; overload;
var
  wStart, wEnd: PChar;
  wIndex, Loop: integer;
  wLoopIDX: integer;
begin
  wIndex := 1;
  wLoopIDX := 1;
  wEnd := PChar(ParseLine);
  if (FromIDX > -1) and (FromIDX < Length(ParseLine)) then
  begin
    inc(wEnd, FromIDX);
    wIndex := FromPOS;
    wLoopIDX := FromIDX;
  end;
  wStart := wEnd;

  for Loop := wLoopIDX to Length(ParseLine) do
  begin
    if (wEnd^ = ParseSep) then
    begin
      if wIndex = ParseNum then
        break
      else
      begin
        inc(wIndex);
        inc(wEnd);
        wStart := wEnd;
      end;
    end
    else
      inc(wEnd);
  end;

  if wIndex = ParseNum then
  begin
    SetString(result, PChar(ParseLine), wStart - pChar(ParseLine));
    if result = #0 then
      result := '';
    result := result + updateText + pchar(wEnd);
    FromIDX := wEnd - PChar(ParseLine);
    FromPOS := ParseNum;
  end
  else
    raise Exception.Create('Index not found');
end;

function UpdateSectionPos(const ParseLine, UpdateText: string; ParseNum: integer; const ParseSep: char; const QuotedStrChar: char; var FromIDX, FromPOS: integer):string; overload;
var
  wStart, wEnd: PChar;
  wIndex, Loop: integer;
  wInQuote: boolean;
  wLoopIDX: integer;
begin
  wInQuote := false;
  wIndex := 1;
  wLoopIDX := 1;

  wEnd := PChar(ParseLine);
  if (FromIDX > -1) and (FromIDX < Length(ParseLine)) then
  begin
    inc(wEnd, FromIDX);
    wIndex := FromPOS;
    wLoopIDX := FromIDX;
  end;
  wStart := wEnd;

  for Loop := wLoopIDX to Length(ParseLine) do
  begin
    if (wEnd^ = QuotedStrChar) then
      wInQuote := not wInQuote;

    if not wInQuote and (wEnd^ = ParseSep) then
    begin
      if wIndex = ParseNum then
        break
      else
      begin
        inc(wIndex);
        inc(wEnd);
        wStart := wEnd;
      end;
    end
    else
      inc(wEnd);
  end;

  if wIndex = ParseNum then
  begin
    SetString(result, PChar(ParseLine), wStart - pChar(ParseLine));
    if result = #0 then
      result := '';
    result := result + AnsiQuotedStr(updateText, QuotedStrChar) + pchar(wEnd);
    FromIDX := wEnd - PChar(ParseLine);
    FromPOS := ParseNum;
  end
  else
    raise Exception.Create('Index not found');
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function I use. It supports any-length delimiter (for splitting CRLF-separated string, f.i.) and `AllowEmpty` parameter which determines whether empty elements would be omitted or returned.

```
function Split(const Str: string; Delim: string; AllowEmpty: Boolean): TStringDynArray;
var CurrDelim, NextDelim, CurrIdx: Integer;
begin
  if Str = '' then begin SetLength(Result, 0); Exit; end;
  CurrDelim := 1; CurrIdx := 0; SetLength(Result, 16);
  repeat
    if CurrIdx = Length(Result) then
      SetLength(Result, CurrIdx + 16);                

    NextDelim := PosEx(Delim, Str, CurrDelim);        
    if NextDelim = 0 then NextDelim := Length(Str)+1; // the end of the string
    Result[CurrIdx] := Copy(Str, CurrDelim, NextDelim - CurrDelim);
    CurrDelim := NextDelim + Length(Delim);

    if (Result[CurrIdx] <> '') or AllowEmpty
      then Inc(CurrIdx)
      else Continue;
  until CurrDelim > Length(Str);
  SetLength(Result, CurrIdx);                      // cut the array to actual length
end;
```